# How to play poker online?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, wine

I would like to play online poker but most of poker-rooms (pokerstars and so on) do not give the possiblity to install the software on Ubuntu 14.04.

I prefer to do not use WINE because my notebook is not so "strong", any ideas?

Comment: According to pokerstars' website [they neither have a client, nor do they care to make one](http://www.pokerstars.com/poker/download/faq/#CanIrunPokerStarsonLinuxieUbuntuFedoraetc). Try WINE

Answer (score 2):

If the software is not for Ubuntu and only for Windows WINE is going to be one of your only hopes.

If you absolutely do not want to use WINE I would recommend trying to find some poker sites that are browser based and do not need to install software.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to get some of the Windows-only poker programs to work in WINE - there weren't any answers at the time & they just wouldn't work.

What *did* work was running Windows in a **virtual machine** (like **VirtualBox**) and installing the programs there. MS even offers some free versions of old Windows (like XP) for testing IE compatibility, and you can test IE by seeing if it works with your poker sites & programs too...

Here's a couple of links to the Windows VM "images" (a virtual hard drive you load in a VM client). There are some odd time limits, but with a VM they're still useful.

- [Windows Virtual PC VHDs for testing websites with different Internet Explorer versions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575) - Older from 2012, includes XP, worked with VirtualBox
- [Test versions of IE using Virtual Machines](https://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads) - From 2014, includes XP in "VirutalBox for Linux"